# AngularFirebaseList get keys and Value

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I am trying to use the real time database of Firebase and I have created an API for the list of books and their prices like this.

```
{  
  "Books":[
        {"Angular 4": "$9.99"},
        {"HTML 5": "$10.99"},
        {"CSS3": "$21.90"}
    ]
}
```

After importing all the required dependencies of AngularFirebase from angularfire2 package in npm, I have written the following code to retrieve the values from the database:

```
booklists: AngularFireList<any[]>;
booklistCollection: Observable<any[]>;

constructor(public angularFireDatabase: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.booklists = angularFireDatabase.list('/Books');
    this.booklistCollection = this.booklists.snapshotChanges();
}
```

And in the app.component.html, I have written the following code to iterate through the observables.

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let booklist of booklistCollection | async">
      {{ booklist.key }} : {{ booklist.value }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But, the output only contains the keys and not the values.

I am not able to figure out a method to fetch both keys and values at the same time. I know that the values can be fetched separately using **valueChanges()** method of the **AngularFirebaseList** but I need a way to get both keys and values in a single go.

Comment: This should work even without the snapshotChanges() as that is used to preserve the data.  Are you getting the titles printed as the keys, or the Firebase keys?  Can you show the output, and maybe the dashboard view of your data in Firebase?

Comment: with this kind of data structure It only worked for me when used snapshots.forEach(childSnapshot => { key = Object.keys(childSnapshot)[0]; val = childSnapshot[key]; }); Maybe you can try booklist[booklist.key] for the value.

Answer (score 3):

For each item in `snapshotChanges()`, try `item.payload.val()`

Comment: Thanks for formatting it, Syscall, but I'm not sure it was necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I Solved the same problem as follows. `payload.val()` returns the object

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let booklist of booklistCollection | async">
      {{ booklist.key }} : {{ booklist?.payload?.val()?.value }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```